# point-free using String.prototype.concat() not working as expected

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, concatenation, pointfree

I got an unexpected behavior when I try to concat two strings in a point-free style:

```js
    const namespace = "ns-";
    const names = ['bar','foo', 'baz'];
    
    names.map((i) => namespace.concat(i)) // ok
    names.map(namespace.concat) // ERROR: String.prototype.concat called on null or undefined
```

I thought I could omit the parameter on function call since AFAIK  `a => fn(a)` is the same as calling `fn`. But in the case of using concat() it is not working.

Obviously, I'm missing something on the language, but I don't know what it is

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Called_on_incompatible_type

Comment: as @ChrisG commented the useful link you can see that the problem is related to `this` keyword, the right `point-free` here could be something like this: `const concatNameSpace = (v)=> namespace.concat(v); names.map(concatNameSpace) `

Comment: `names.map(namespace.concat.bind(namespace))`

Comment: "a => fn(a) is the same as calling fn" yes... in a *functional* language. But Javascript is a mishmash of different programming paradigms, architectural styles, etc. As are most old, popular languages. In JS when you pass an *object method* as a higher-order function you lose the *context* of the object the method is putatively called on, the string `namespace` in your case. Sometimes it doesn't matter: you can e.g. pass `console.log` around as a function. But when it does you can wrap it in a lambda or use `Function.prototype.bind` as I did in my earlier comment.